# Uncaught Error: No module: myApp Plunker inside

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I have a simple setup of an angularjs application. The scripts are loaded with requirejs. When loading the application, I get `Uncaught Error: No module: myapp` in the console.

The scripts are loaded in order scripts.js (requirejs configuration), jquery, angular and then app.

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7JNPrnPsW4tCQkoO0EZX?p=preview).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the `ng-app` directive from the `html` element. See the updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ypEEXSPJX5Y4WqsPymXc?p=preview).

First, the directive is not necessary, because you already manual bootstrap AngularJS (and `ng-app` is simply the shortcut to do that).

Second, the reason AngularJS reports the error is because when it processes `ng-app` (upon document ready event), the module file (in `app.js`) has not been loaded by RequireJS (that's why you have to do manual bootstrap in the first place).

Comment: This is the fix for an issue with Netbeans 8.0.2 and Angular-Seed [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/)